# Windows automated batch file for building of docker images

Tags: windows, docker, batch-file

You might say why you want to automate that? Because I'm tired to update 4-5 repos every week and push them manually in Docker. So I want to use a simple windows batch-file to automate that.

I got my Dockerfile and my commands:

```
docker build -t project .
docker tag project repo/project:tag
docker push repo/project:tag:project
```

The problem I have is that for example the build command needs a bit time and the commands should only be called when the immediate predecessor is done.

```
START /B
```

somehow did not work.

Comment: If you have to use the `START` command, _which is doubtful_, you'd probably want to us its `/WAIT` option! Please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information.

Comment: @Compo I'm not sure what to use for this purpose. What instead of start then?

Comment: Have you tried it without? What happens and when? We're supposed to be here to help you fix a specific reproducible issue, and for that we need debugging information! The likely thing is that docker, doesn't just deploy the payload and end when the payload has completed, it acts like a stub, firing off one or more different commands, returning as complete as soon as it has started it/them. A well written program would not do that, so the issue may be with docker itself, its settings, or the payload it deploys.

Comment: Batch files will not run the next command until the previous command is finished. Your second `docker` execution should not run until the first one is done.